# expo scanner not returning result when barcode is scanned

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, api, expo

My react-native app does not return any error when I scan a barcode but it also doesn't return the result. It is an expo project and expo-barcode-scanner module is being used. The alert system works perfectly but even I try to do a simple return, it doesn't output anything. Please help.

**ScanScreen.js**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext  } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Button } from 'react-native';
import { BarCodeScanner } from 'expo-barcode-scanner';
import OpenFoodContext from '../../context/openfood/openfoodContext'
import Spinner from '../../components/Spinner';



const ScanScreen = () => {

  const openFoodContext = useContext(OpenFoodContext);
  const { products, loading, } = openFoodContext;

  const [hasPermission, setHasPermission] = useState(null);
  const [scanned, setScanned] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const { status } = await BarCodeScanner.requestPermissionsAsync();
      setHasPermission(status === 'granted');
    })();
  }, []);

  const handleBarCodeScanned = () => {
    setScanned(true);

    if (loading){
      return <Spinner />
  } else{

    return (
      <View >
        {products.map((product) =>{
        <Text>{product.product}</Text>
  })}   
      </View>
      );
    }
  };

  if (hasPermission === null) {
    return <Text>Requesting for camera permission</Text>;
  }
  if (hasPermission === false) {
    return <Text>No access to camera</Text>;
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
    <BarCodeScanner
      onBarCodeScanned={scanned ? undefined : handleBarCodeScanned}
      style={StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject}
    />
    {scanned && <Button title={'Tap to Scan Again'} onPress={() => setScanned(false)} />}
  </View>
);
};


export default ScanScreen;
```

**OpenFoodState.js**

```
import  React, {useReducer} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import OpenFoodContext from './openfoodContext';
import OpenFoodReducer from './openfoodReducer';
import {
    GET_ITEMS,
    SET_LOADING,
    
} from '../types';



const OpenFoodState = props => {
    const initialState ={
        products: [],
        loading: false
    }

    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(OpenFoodReducer, initialState);


// Get List
const getProducts = async () => {
    setLoading();

    const res = await axios.get(
      `https://world.openfoodfacts.org/api/v0/product/737628064502.json`
    );
    dispatch({
        type: GET_ITEMS,
        payload: res.data.items
    });
  };

  // Set Loading
  const setLoading = () => dispatch ({type: SET_LOADING});


return <OpenFoodContext.Provider
value={{

    products: state.products,
    loading: state.loading,
    getProducts
}}
>
    {props.children}
</OpenFoodContext.Provider>
}

export default OpenFoodState;
```

**openfoodReducer**

```
import {
    GET_ITEMS,
    SET_LOADING,
    
} from '../types';

export default (state, action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case GET_ITEMS:
            return {
                ...state,
               products: action.payload,
               loading: false 
            }
            case SET_LOADING:
            return {
              ...state,
              loading: true
            }
        default:
            return state;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your barcode scan handler function i.e., handleBarCodeScanned you receive params for type of bar code and also the data in bar code.

```
const handleBarCodeScanned = ({type, data}) => {
    setScanned(true);
    console.log("Check out the data from scan here", type, data)
    if (loading){
      return <Spinner />
  } else{

    return (
      <View >
        {products.map((product) =>{
        <Text>{product.product}</Text>
  })}   
      </View>
      );
    }
  };
```

check out this function

Comment: Thank you. But this is still just a console.log. I'm trying to return data now from a real life API and render it to screen.

Comment: instead of console you can use a useState to update the state and use it to render to screen

Comment: Please can you give an example? A little bit confused. Are the type & data props a constant/fixed name? I ask because I already created a context to manage the state with a prop named "products". Do I need some kind of logic to match the products prop with the data & type props? If it's no problem, can I share the GitHub repo with you so you can take a look at the full scope?

Answer (score 0):

The API response returned "product" as object so it is `res.data.product` not `res.data.items.`